# how to create table in MS Word using C#

Tags: c#, com

i want to create a dynamic table in MS word using C#. when i submit my form ,a table (in word)should be created and this table should be fill with value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here's msdn tutorial on how to solve your problem: [Walkthrough: Creating a Table in Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192483%28office.11%29.aspx)